# Unable to use ORDER BY in a simple query

Tags: mysql

I really wonder why data doesn't show whenever I use ORDER BY in such a simple query below:

I've already created a column named 'order' in categories table. The order columns holds the seniority level each category as in the image:[image]

```
        <?php
         include('inc/config.php');
         $sql= "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY order DESC";
         $stmt = $pdo->query($sql); 
        ?>
         <h1 class="text-center">Choose a <span class="elec">level</span></h1>
        <?php
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="level" id=<?php echo $row['catid'];?> value="<?php echo $row['catid'];?>">
        <label><?php echo $row['catname'];?></label><br/>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word and you need to escape using backticks

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY `order` DESC
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

Answer (score 1):

The word `order` is a reserved word in MySQL - because it's used in `ORDER BY` clauses. If you surround it by backticks, it will work:

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY `order` DESC
```